# Readable stream `_read` not called in test

Tags: ava, node-streams

I have the following simplified ava test case. When I run it by ava `_read()` never get called (ONDATA is OK). On the other hand, when I run this test body (without assertions) as node script I always get `_read()` called as expected.
Probably I miss some key feature, please advice.

```
test('...', async t => {
  class R extends stream.Readable {
    _read() { console.log('READ'); }
  }
  const rs = new R();

  rs.on('data', data => {
    console.log('ONDATA ', data.toString());
  });
  rs.push(Buffer.from('data'));
  // t.is(...)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't immediately recall in what scenario `_read()` should get called, but most likely your test ends before that happens. You have an `async` test but you don't seem to `await` anything. Try returning an explicit promise or otherwise use `test.cb()` so you can end the test with `t.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Essentially I messed up with readable stream callbacks and `async test`. The desired test looks like

```
test.cb('...', t => {
  class R extends stream.Readable {
    _read() {
      console.log('READ');
      // t.pass() or t.end() HERE
    }
  }
  const rs = new R();

  rs.on('data', data => {
    // t.pass() or t.end() HERE
    console.log('ONDATA ', data.toString());
  });
  rs.push(Buffer.from('data'));
})
```